# Creating a table in R with two FOR cicles does not fill the dataframe "Maux" correctly

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

when I'm trying to create the dataframe from a table with a lot of data (`totalSurvey`), filtering with these two for-loops (`x` for Gender and `y` for Age), when the loop finishes it only has data for Men and Age 16. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (x in 1:2) {
  for (y in 1:4){
    vGen <-ifelse(x==1, "Hombre" , ifelse(x==2, "Mujer"))
    vEdad <-ifelse(y==1, "13" , ifelse( y==2, "14", ifelse( y==3, "15", "16")))
    
    Maux <- filter(totalSurv, Genero == vGen, Edad == vEdad)  
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you make this question more reproducible? (1) Syntax is broken, the `for` loop is not closed out; (2) we don't know what `x` is, nor `totalSurv`. Lastly, (3) you overwrite the contents of `Maux` in each pass of the `for` loop, only the last (`y=4`) pass is retained after the loop.

Comment: Also, you're missing the "no=" argument to `vGen`'s inner `ifelse`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. "x" is a local variable that I use in this loop. I don't know how to avoid the overwriting the contents of Maux. Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I need "Maux" df has all the ages and gender, not only Woman and Age 16, something wrong in the loop I have... dk

Comment: My answer should work, there is no need for nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a different methodology. I'll guess lacking sample data:

```r
eg <- expand.grid(Genero = c("Hombre", "Mujer"), Edad = as.character(13:16))
eg$Maux <- seq_len(nrow(eg))
eg
#   Genero Edad Maux
# 1 Hombre   13    1
# 2  Mujer   13    2
# 3 Hombre   14    3
# 4  Mujer   14    4
# 5 Hombre   15    5
# 6  Mujer   15    6
# 7 Hombre   16    7
# 8  Mujer   16    8
```

From here, merge/join it in:

```r
left_join(eg, totalSurv, by = c("Genero", "Edad"))
```

and you should have a frame (`tbl_df`) with just the data you need. The `Maux` field here is an integer indicating to which row in the `eg` starting frame the data on that row belongs.

---

An alternative that is much less efficient but might be more readable for you:

```r
lst_of_frames <- bind_rows(lapply(1:2, function(x) {
  bind_rows(lapply(1:4, function(y) {
    vGen <-ifelse(x==1, "Hombre" , ifelse(x==2, "Mujer"))
    vEdad <-ifelse(y==1, "13" , ifelse( y==2, "14", ifelse( y==3, "15", "16")))
    filter(totalSurv, Genero == vGen, Edad == vEdad)
  }))
}))
```

All I did was replace your `for` loops with `lapply` calls, wrapped each of them in a `dplyr::bind_rows`, and dumped your `ifelse` and `filter` code inside the inner loop.

The alternative is to start with a 0-row frame and append (`rbind` in R-speak) each result to the empty frame. I'll say up front, this method is a *bad idea*:

```r
Maux <- totalSurv[0,] # intentionally empty, but with all columns/classes
for (x in 1:2) {
  for (y in 1:4){
    vGen <-ifelse(x==1, "Hombre" , ifelse(x==2, "Mujer"))
    vEdad <-ifelse(y==1, "13" , ifelse( y==2, "14", ifelse( y==3, "15", "16")))
    
    Maux <- bind_rows(Maux, filter(totalSurv, Genero == vGen, Edad == vEdad))
  }
}
```

It's worth repeating, this is a bad idea. Why? Adding iteratively to a frame in R is inefficient, because each time you add even just one row, it copies all of the frame's contents into a new object. This means that if your `Maux` has 99999 rows and you want to add just 1 more row, then you have those 99999 rows in memory *twice*. The memory footprint is one thing, each time you do this it takes more time to copy all of that stuff around.

But it still *works*, and if you're only doing this a few times with a few rows, then all is fine and the sky will not fall. But don't take my offering it here as a suggestion that it is the right way to do it *in general*.

(BTW: I still haven't fixed the incorrect `ifelse(x==2, "Mujer")`: there should be a third object. Or just replace that whole line with

```r
ifelse(x==1, "Hombre" , "Mujer")
```

---

One last thought: you don't need to iterate over numbers, if the only thing you're doing with those numbers if `ifelse`ing them. You could instead do

```r
Maux <- totalSurv[0,]
for (vGen in c("Hombre", "Mujer")) {
  for (vEdad in as.character(13:16)) {
    Maux <- bind_rows(Maux, filter(totalSurv, Genero == vGen, Edad == vEdad))
  }
}
# or
Maux <- bind_rows(lapply(c("Hombre", "Mujer"), function(vGen) {
  bind_rows(lapply(as.character(13:16), function(vEdad) {
    filter(totalSurv, Genero == vGen, Edad == vEdad)
  }))
}))
```

for a much more compact and direct-code experience.

(But I still argue that my first `left_join` method is the most direct, and allows you to define very specific combinations that you need. I updated it for your updated column names, btw.)

Comment: Thank YOUUU!! it worked GREAT!! you rock it, man! thanks a lot, really!